# Why do I need an administrator account to mount a network drive via ssh?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, powershell, mount, openssh

I'm trying to mount a network drive over OpenSSH  on Windows 10 (authenticated with username and password of a non-admin user). When I use the `net use` command (via a PowerShell script) to mount a local folder to a network drive within ssh, I get the following error:

`The password is invalid for <PATH>`

When I run the exact same script on the machine locally with the same user, it works without admin access. If I enter admin credentials over SSH, it also works. Is there any way to make this work over ssh without admin access?

EDIT:

According to this issus:
https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/139
what I'm doing should be possible as long as a username/password is used to authenticate ssh.

Comment: This is an OS state/operational/Security boundary. Not a PowerShell issue or PS code issue. Similar Q&A's exist. For example [openssh windows bad owner or permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926386/openssh-windows-bad-owner-or-permissions). Windows network drives are mapped to an existing user profile on the current or target host; when you remote into a host, you are not using a local profile, not a network logon session, hence your local success.

Comment: I understand this, but my problem is that I cannot mount a new network drive within the ssh session (without admin priviliges)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment...

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/139

> "This is by design. Mapped network drives are associated with a logon
> session. SSH remote sessions are created with an associated network
> logon session (these are independent of other logon sessions)."
>
> You can map drive within sshd sesion if you did login with password as
> follows:

```
net use t: \vboxsrv\sharename
```

> If logged in via public key or the remote share need a different
> username and password credential, you can do as follows:

```
net use t: \vboxsrv\sharename /user:domainname/username *
```

> then type the password when prompted.
>
> Just to make a comment on network drive letters.
>
> I personally don't like them, because they had a lot of side effects,
> which are not always visible immediately.

- they are only valid in the session (desktop session) they are created
  in. They are not visible in the session where the Windows Services
  are running in. This is also a problem when writing applications you
  are goint to run as Scheduled Task
- They are user specifc. (keep in mind, that a user account name is
  only a label, the user is internal idendified by a unique identifier
  (SID), which is always different for local acounts on different
  machines and domain accounts. Create a user "peter" on a local
  machine, deleting the account and create it again on the same machine
  will result in two different SIDs for this user (with of corse
  different home directories). c:\users\peter is owned by the first
  "peter" logged on to the machine. The second user Peter will get an
  appendis of computername or domainname (depending where the second
  users belongs to). If this is still not unique, a number is appended
  to the username.domain.0001 (in case of recreated users after
  deletion)
- if you define persistent network drive letters - they are not working
  outside an explorer context. Only the explorer.exe able to reconnect
  them
- Network drives connected in explorer are not accessible in elevated
  programs and vice versa
- They are limiting the number of disk volumes you can mount on servers

  - the alphabet still has only 25 Letters.

> Since Windows Vista we are able to use Symbolic Links, allowing you to
> link UNC path based Directories and Files into the local filesystem,
> without using network drive letters.
>
> If you need to use a different credential on the network connect, then
> you should use the Windows Credential Manager (Control Panel) to store
> the credentials to this location. If you want to define the
> credentials in cmd.exe, powershell or ssh - then use cmdkey.exe - it
> will store it in the Windows Credential Manager.

Comment: I did find this thread but it indicates that if you log in with a username and password you cant mount a drive with `net use`, but my problem is that I cant mount a drive *within* the sshd session, even though I log in with username and password. According to the first quote of your answer, this should be possible.